# How to Add Sass Files to Be Tracked with Git Ubuntu Terminal After I added Ignore File

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, ubuntu

Hello when I first created this Sass project I used git add . to track everything but instead it tracked all of my node modules and nothing else.

To Remove the node modules to be tracked I created a .ignorefile (With /node_modules inside file) and it removed all of the node modules but when I use git add . I get an error message saying  "on branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean"

So now that I got this error how do I tracked all of my files? I am working with Sass for this project. I am also using ubuntu in my VS Code Terminal

[image: Git Ubuntu Terminal Screenshot]

UPDATE: I doing some research and I decided to use `git add --all` .
now its saying

Changes to be committed:
(use "git restore --staged ..." to unstage)

And then it shows the files I made changes to. Are my files being tracked now if not what do I need to do in order to get these tracked so I can upload to github?

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Comment: Did you remove already tracked files from index? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore?rq=1

Comment: "on branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean" is not an error it is just an information.

Comment: If git add . didnt work what should I use instead?

Comment: When I created the git ignore file it removed all of the node modules folders from being tracked.